# The server-side program does not achieve the desired output

Tags: java, java-17

This is the code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket sc = new ServerSocket(8000);
            while(true) {
                Socket socket = sc.accept();
                InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                int len = 0;
                String str = null;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
                List<Byte> byteL = new ArrayList<>();
                do {
                    len =in.read(bytes);
                    for (int i = 0;i < len;i++) {
                        byteL.add(bytes[i]);
                    }
                    byte[] byteLs = new byte[byteL.size()];
                    for(int j = 0;j < byteL.size();j++) {
                        byteLs[j] = byteL.get(j);
                    }
                    str = new String(byteLs,0,byteLs.length);
                    System.out.println(str);
                    if (len == -1) {
                        byteL.clear();
                        str = null;
                    }
                } while (len != -1);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want the server to output client input in the console, but the program stops at "len =in.read(bytes); ", which causes me to be unable to empty the collection to guarantee that the contents of each output are correct.

Comment: The `read` method will return `-1` when reaching the end of the stream, which implies that it has been closed. There is no other end criteria in your code. When the sending side doesn’t close the stream, the receiving side doesn’t know how long the string should be. Besides that, it’s very inefficient to request 8 byte chunks and copy them to a `List<Byte>`, instead of straight-forwardly use a larger `byte[]` array (and directly copy from `byte[]` to the new `byte[]` when you need a larger capacity).

Comment: And furthermore you need to detect `len == -1` a lot earlier than you do. Don't let all that copying code run even if `len == -1`. It's just a waste of time.